# Computed Observable set to null doesn't update GUI

Tags: knockout.js

I have found that if a computed observable is set to some value, and is then re-evaluated and returns `null`, that the previous computed value is being used in bindings/the GUI isn't updating. This seems odd, and I'd like to ask if I'm doing something wrong, or if this is the expected behaviour?

An example (http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/18081/):

I am using a computed observable to return a class name used in a `css` binding. The binding can be a class name or no class at all. The template:

```
<p data-bind="css: textColour">Coloured text</p>
```

The computed observable first evaluates to 'green', and the coloured text turns green (I've defined the css for class 'green'). When the computed observable re-evaluates and returns `null`, the text colour remains green however.

```
that.success = ko.observable(true);
that.textColour = ko.computed(function() {
    if (that.success()) {
        return 'green';
    } else {
        return null;
    }
});
```

I return null to remove the class from the binding. Why doesn't this work? I have found that if I return `undefined`, or nothing at all (also `undefined`), that the binding updates as expected and the green colour is removed.

This problem isn't blocking me going forward, however is questioning my understanding of KO. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be considered a bug in the binding. I suggest you open an issue in Github about it: https://github.com/knockout/knockout

Another workaround is to return an empty string.

```
that.textColour = ko.computed(function() {
    if (that.success()) {
        return 'green';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Michael - issue opened at https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1468.